# &nbsp; changes to &amp;nbsp in asp.net mvc html.dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, indentation, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to show items with indention in html.dropdownlist

this is code in controller

```
IEnumerable<ViewModels.testvm> test = db.Database.SqlQuery<ViewModels.testvm>(@"WITH tree (id, parentid, level, title, rn) as 
(
   some code
)
***********SELECT id,REPLICATE('&nbsp;',level) + title as title
FROM tree
order by RN");
ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(test, "ID", "Title");
```

as you can see I add &nbsp to dropdown items in replecate

but the problem is  &nbsp shows in dropdown.

this is view > source result:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="ParentID" name="ParentID"><option 

value="10">Menu1</option>
<option value="11">&amp;nbsp;Sub1</option>
<option value="14">&amp;nbsp;Submenu1</option>
<option value="12">Menu2</option>
<option value="16">&amp;nbsp;sub2</option>
<option value="13">Menu3</option>
<option value="15">&amp;nbsp;sub3</option>
<option value="17">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;sub sub</option>
<option value="22">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;sub3 sub sub</option>
<option value="19">menu4</option>
<option value="20">&amp;nbsp;sub4</option>
<option value="21">menu5</option>
</select>
```

as you can see `&nbsp;` converted to `&amp;nbsp;`

I tried `"\xA0"` instead of `&nbsp` but it shows in dropdown too!

I think html.raw can solve this, but I don't know how can I use it with html.dropdownlist.

this is view

```
<div class="col-md-10">

@Html.DropDownList( "ParentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-
control" })

</div>
```

any Idea?

---

**Edit**

by changing view like this the problem solved:
I tried this after checked a post as answer

```
   <select class="form-control" id="ParentID" name="ParentID">
        <option value="0">First Level</option>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ParentID)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@Html.Raw(@item.Text)</option>
        }
    </select>
```

Comment: I think you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239348/how-to-use-html-raw-in-mvc-razor-dropdownlist. It's hard to use `Html.Raw` for each `SelectListItem` select items, try to use CSS-based styling instead.

Comment: it's a dynamic n level dropdownlist, how can I style each item based on it's level? I mean, margin:10px; for level one, margin: 10px*level for another items?

Comment: You cannot do this using `DropDownList()` - the methods builds its own `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and the result is encoded. You could do it using a (say) hyphen, otherwise you will need to generate the html manually or create a custom `HtmlHelper` extension method

Comment: Are you looking to **group** your items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create the dropdown list assuming you place your collection in a ViewModel member called `ParentIDs`:

The View:

```
@if (Model.ParentIDs.Any())
{
    <select class="form-control" id="ParentID" name="ParentID">
        @foreach (var item in Model.ParentIDs)
        {
            if (Model.ParentID == item.id)
            {
                 <option value="@item.id" selected>@item.title</option>
            }
            else
            {
                 <option value="@item.id">@item.title</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
}
```

Comment: Locke125 ,I tried something like that before, but it didn't keep selected value of manually created dropdownlist, I will try again, and if any success, will write here.

Comment: I added a bit of code that could help setting the selected state. You'll have to have that somewhere in the model though.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue when trying to render the `TM` symbol within my dropdown options using `&trade;`. I was able to resolve it by using the `.Replace()` method within my extension class in order to convert the `&amp;` back to `&`

```
private static MvcHtmlString CustomItemDropDownListFor(MvcHtmlString source, string sourceItemName, string sourceItemValue = "", string targetItemValue = "")
{
    string htmlString = source.ToHtmlString();
    htmlString = htmlString.Replace("&amp;", "&");
    return new MvcHtmlString(htmlString);
}
```